# Bootstrap / iPhone mobile - Carousel not displaying correctly

Tags: html, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have built / building a website using Bootstrap and everything is going well. Site displays as it should on browsers, tablets etc .. but when viewing on iphone , the carouseousel is squashed by 50% , I am now left scratching my head with the solution on this.

Could someone help.. the site isis www.p81.co.uk , you u will see the carousel on the homepage but as said, you need to view on an iphone to see the issue.